# Why doesn't componentDidUpdate log the real result like useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following examples which log user clicks with time out, first uses `useEffect` and second uses `componentDidUpdate`:

```
const UseEffectCounter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`You clicked ${count} times`);
        }, 3000);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class ComponentDidUpdateCounter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`);
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})}>+1</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The first example logs sequentially after the 3 seconds timeout, which I understand that each time `setCount` is invoked, the state updates and the component re-renders, thus triggers `useEffect` on each re-render, and logs the sequential `count` value.

I don't fully understand the 2nd example: if `componentDidUpdate` runs after each update, thus each `setState` on button click, why doesn't it log the `count` value sequentially but logs the latest calculation of `count` for number of click times?

Answer (score 2):

First code example that uses `useEffect` hook, logs the value of `count` sequentially because of closures. Callback function of `setTimeout` closes over the value of `count` and each callback logs the value of count that it closed over.

Second code example logs the updated value of `count` because, unlike  the functional component example, there is no closure and in class component, React mutates `this.state.count` to always point to the latest value of the state.

**P.S:** For more details, read this [`blog post on useEffect hook`](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov where he goes over a [`similar example`](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything) and explains the difference between the two code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Because by the time the timeout goes off, `this.state.count` has changed. The value is not locked in when you start the timeout, you're looking it up when it goes off.

With the useEffect code, you're logging a local `const` which can never change. Even if the component rerenders, that will result in a *different* local const being created, and the one your timeout is referencing is unchanged.